# Transport/Message security with SSL

Tags: wcf

Why would I require SSL port when I can achieve Transport/Message encryption for a WCF service.

I mean the messages will be encrypted. So why have a SSL encrypted port?

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why you'd want SSL security (a.k.a. transport-security) instead of message-level (i.e., WS-Security) security:

- SSL is implemented by a lot more clients / servers than the WS-Security protocol
- With SSL not only the message body is encrypted, but other parts of it are as well (such as headers and transport headers
- Some endpoints do not support WS-Security, such as those which use `webHttpBinding`
- Depending on the platform, SSL encryption (or parts of it) may be implemented in hardware, making it more efficient
- During development, it's easier to inspect messages when they're encrypted with SSL than when they use message encryption

There are still many cases where message security is more interesting than transport security, such as end-to-end encryption (SSL works by encrypting per-hop). As always, the best solution will depend on your scenario.

Comment: Transport security by default provides client to server encryption. So why do I need SSL port?

Comment: SSL *is* one kind of transport security.